# Google Translator API

Tags: api, google-translator-toolkit

I am using Google Translator API to translate English resource file to Spanish. I have around 6000 keys in my resource file. Right now I am passing keys one by one and getting the result. After some frequent hits(after some 1000 keys) to Google site I get 403 Terms of service abuse error.

Is there any other way I could translate all 6000 key values to Spanish?

I am using GoogleTranslateAPI_0.4_alpha API and below is the code.

```
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader (filename);
  rsxr.UseResXDataNodes=true;

    ResXDataNode node;
  AssemblyName[] assemblies;
  string value=string.Empty;
  string comment=string.Empty;

  foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
  {

    node = (ResXDataNode)d.Value;
    assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetReferencedAssemblies ();
    value=node.GetValue (assemblies).ToString ();

    try
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (value))
      {

        TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient ("my proxy address");
        value=client.Translate (value.ToString () ,"en" ,"es");


      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

      value="dummy";

    }

  }

  rsxr.Close ();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you violate the Google terms of service, so your bet bet is to get a human to do it.
There are commercial programs that do translation, but I have not found any I like or even feel adequately do the job (a Google search will turn up a number of them and you can pick one).
Anyway, machine translations generally don't do so well with user interfaces because they are tuned for general conversation and not for the shorter blobs of text (not sentences) that you generally find in a program (so says a guy I know who works for Google).

Answer (score 0):

Pay for it:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/pricing.html

See also Microsoft Translator:
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb